# Why do I have a calendar called weather? And has nothing to do with anything

Tags: calendar

I have a calendar called "Weather: Auckland, NZ" 
The Weather calendar on the sidebar is checked and it's called "Weather: Springfield, MO" And the "calendar" shows three days for my zip code. Of course I can share, add, use, save, import, export, make into orgami, but can't delete. WHy does it exist? Where did it come from? I haven't been to any of the places associated with the calendar. I live in the zip code. OH, and it's it's own calendar. Not associated with any other emails or calendars. A color all it's own. Which, of course, I can also change. Any idea?

Comment: The question is very confusing.  Can you take some screenshots to add to your question?  Maybe that will help clarify things.  Also, please add your OS version and machine info.

Comment: If the answer below is correct you should select it so people won't waste time looking for an answer!

Answer (score 1):

It is a app from MetService (MetService NZ Weather) on App Store, that you must have downloaded.

[image]

[image]